# Vue router and vuex issue with redirecting based on a value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a Vue application that I am trying to have it that when the user has not paid and trial is over they are redirected to `/billing` and displayed an error message. I also would like it so that if they have paid or are still in their trial period that they can use the application.

storeUser code in my store.js

```
storeUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user
      state.isPaid = user.isPaid
      state.isTrial = user.isTrial
 },
```

data passed into storeUser as 'user'

```
{
  name: "Joe",
  isPaid: false,
  isTrial: false
}
```

Data showing in my vuex store using the chrome vui extention

```
{
  name: "Joe",
  isPaid: null,
  isTrial: null
}
```

Not sure why the data is being input wrong since I can console.log the correct data in the storeUser function. However if I look into the user portion I can see it as the correct false values. When I try to specify this in the code below for the vue router it says that is can't read it because it's null. I assume this is just an async issue.

state in store.js

```js
state: {
    token: null,
    isPaid: null, 
    isTrial: null,
    error: {
      registerErrorMessage: '',
      loginErrorMessage: '',
      resetError: ''
    },
    user: null
  }
```

main.js which contains my vue router

```js
} else if(to.path != '/billing' && !(store.state.isPaid && store.state.isTrial)) {
    next({
      path: '/billings',
      query: {
         paid: false,
      }
  })
```

Can anyone spot a potential issue or maybe a solution to my issue?  This code should be enough to reproduce the issue though if missing I can provide more, there is no public repo to show the rest of the code in.

EDIT**
So something weird happened.. I am now seeing more correct data than before (isPaid and isTrial are valid) however I'm still not able to go to other routes now.
Adding output of store.state at the beginning of my beforeEach

```js
{
  token: 'random string',
  isPaid: true,
  isTrial: false,
  error: {},
  user: {
    name: "Joe",
    isPaid: true,
    isTrial: false
  }
}
```

EDIT 2**

```
storeUser({commit, state}) {
      if(!state.token) return
      axios.get('/user/userInfo')
        .then(res => {
          if(res.data.success) {
            commit('storeUser', {
              name: res.data.user.name,
              isPaid: res.data.user.company.stripe.isPaid,
              isTrial: res.data.user.company.stripe.isTrial
            })
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
```

EDIT 3**
Here is my whole vue route from main.js

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.dispatch('tryAutoLogin')
  console.log(store.state) // this is test only not for prod
  if(!store.state.token && (to.path == '/login' 
    || to.path == '/signup' 
    || to.path == '/forgot' 
    || to.path == '/resend' 
    || to.path.includes('/confirmation/'))) 
  {
    return next()
  } else if (to.path == '/signup') {
    return next({ query: {plan: from.query.plan }})
  } else if(to.path != '/billing' && !(store.state.isPaid && store.state.isTrial)) {
    next({
      path: '/billing',
      query: {
         paid: false,
      }
  })
  } else if(store.state.token) {
    return next()
  } else {
    return next('/login')
  }
})
```

You can see I do the auto login which just checks if a token exists or not that's it. It's not related to the issue.

EDIT 4**

I have an idea but not sure how to implement it.. Use promises to make sure the data is right. My confusion on the promise part is getting them to work together. So I'm think `authUser` mutation then somehow make the `storeUser` action a promise that I can resolve in my beforeEach

Actions

```
tryAutoLogin({commit, dispatch}) {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
   if(!token) {return}
   commit('authUser',{
     token
   })
   dispatch('storeUser')
},


storeUser({commit, state}) {
      if(!state.token) return
      axios.get('/user/userInfo')
        .then(res => {
          if(res.data.success) {
            commit('storeUser', {
              name: res.data.user.name,
              companyName: res.data.user.company.companyName,
              role: res.data.user.role,
              isPaid: res.data.user.company.stripe.isPaid,
              isTrial: res.data.user.company.stripe.isTrial
            })
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
```

Mutations

```
authUser(state, userData) {
  state.token = userData.token
},
storeUser(state, user) {
  state.user = user
  state.isPaid = user.isPaid
  state.isTrial = user.isTrial
},
```

Comment: What is the error specifically referring to? Is it saying that cannot read store.state.x ?

Comment: Can you post the structure of mutations and actions if you are using any?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky It is just saying that it can't read `store.state.user` says it's null which is backed up by the chrome extentsion I am using

Comment: Okay, can you console log store from within where you are doing route logic and share that in your question? It sounds alike store doesn’t even have a state property so I’m curious to see what’s actually in store and then maybe how it’s being imported/defined.

Comment: @JesusGalvan Not sure what you mean? There are tons I am using but only the one I provided really touches the data I'm trying to get to work with.

Comment: There is missing information regarding the structure of your store.js file. 
Could you update the post with the contents of that file?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I added an output of console.log(store.state) that is at the top of my beforeEach

Comment: @JesusGalvan You want the whole file? Can't really do that. I did include the important parts of it. Ie the state and the one mutation that is run and I will add the only thing not already there that could be of use though it shows nothing new that I didn't already explain.

Comment: Are you calling next() it none of these conditions are met? If next isn’t called in each conditional branch, navigation can fail entirely.

Comment: You need to always call next inside the vue-router guards.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I'm not sure exactly what I should be calling it on at this point (head is spinning today), idea is I want this else if to only trigger if the route isn't billing and that both isPaid and isTrial are false, otherwise I'd like it to not trigger and just let the user go to what ever route they want to

Comment: It’s really hard to tell as we are only gets pieces, but you need to look at beforeEach and make sure that each conditional branch, you are calling next() with or without arguments. If you want navigation to continue to the original path, then just call next().

Comment: @JesusGalvan I've added in edit 3 my whole vue router before each that is in my mian.js file so you can see where I am and where I am not calling next

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I just added my whole beforeEach as edit 3 to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a lot of duplicate and confusing code.

Why is there 2 of `isPaid` and `isTrial` in the state?

You also did not use the `name` property you provided to `commit` function.

The commit

```js
commit('storeUser', {
    name: res.data.user.name,
    isPaid: res.data.user.company.stripe.isPaid,
    isTrial: res.data.user.company.stripe.isTrial
});
```

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        userName: '',
        isPaid: false,
        isTrial: false,
    },
    mutations: {
        storeUser(state, data) {
            state.userName = data.name;
            state.isPaid = data.isPaid;
            state.isTrial = data.isTrial;
        },
    },
});
```

Now you access the state `store.state.isPaid` and `store.state.isTrial`.

You can see a working example at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jesgvn/5azp98mn/). If you open up the console you can see how the current state is logged.

Comment: The reason for the duplicate isPaid/isTrial was me seeing if it made a difference being user `state.user` or not. I can remove the first one but not under the user since that's how the data is input. I understand the premis of the accessing the store, I don't think having this duplicate would cause the issues I am having. As for using name vs userName, it is simply what I chose at the time so I had no reason to change it since that part works fine. What doesn't seem to work is the router stuff related to the state. The issue likely lies in the beforeEach section of my code

Comment: @joshk132 You can see a working example at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jesgvn/5azp98mn/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the beforeEach issue which was the main point of this post. I see it shows the value changing, I can get that sometimes - odd with same code works 1/2 times - however the router issue still exists.

Comment: @joshk132 The state might not be available yet (depending on how you are setting the initial state). It might be a race condition where the check is done before that state load. You could delay everything until you have the initial state loaded. Sort of a spinning loader. It is hard to tell without having the actual code. Create a jsfiddle with your actual behavior and I can take a look.

Comment: I've done a bit of console.log statements and it looks like the beforeEach is being a bit odd (maybe not and just async messing with things), so if at the top of the beforeEach I put a console.log it shows the state however if I put a console.log for isPaid and isTrial inside the else if where I evaluate them I get `null` for both values. As for creating a jsfiddle, I don't think I can do that without making my API public

Comment: See my edit 4 for a current idea to get around the null values and not being there at the right time.

Comment: @joshk132 You don’t have to make your full API public, just replicate some of behavior you are getting. It is really difficult to fully assess your problem without a good overview. For example, there is no code about where `tryAutoLogin` is being called.

Comment: See edit 3 code line 2 where I have `store.dispatch('tryAutoLogin')` that's the only place in the whole code base that calls it. As for replicating it, I'll try but probably not get done quickly since it's got a lot of code behind what's being called and also touches multiple micro services.

Comment: @joshk132 Don’t do the tryAutoLogin inside the beforeEach. Try it in your main.js file. Or even in the mounted() method inside your root component.

Comment: Just gave that a try and it broke the application fully, only thing that shows now is the login page. No matter what route (non auth) I go to it now redirects to the login page. I did that long ago when first building the application, it was in the beforeEach as it was the only place in the whole thing where it worked right

Comment: Just tried in the created hook too and same result as the mounted

Comment: @joshk132 Then there is something else that is wrong. You should not be setting the logged in user every single time you are about to go to another route, that’s the point of vue-router and SPA architecture. In that case you should ditch vue-router and do full page loads. What error are you getting?

Comment: What else could be wrong? Everything worked exactly as expected till the issue I posted about asking for help on. Issue seems to be that the if statement is getting `null` instead of a boolean value. What do you mean by `Where error are you getting?` If you mean the redirect to /login, no error message just a redirect as I'd expect when there is no token set in the state. See the first if in the beforeEach in edit 3, you will notice the redirects that work as expected. Only the if with isPaid and isTrial is broken.

Comment: @joshk132 It could be the race issue, the state not being set correctly, or not reading state correctly. Hard to tell without the rest of the code, or a working example. But there are other code smells such as loading state in the router beforeEach (don't do like this). I suggest you fix that first and then continue.

Comment: How would I fix that then? I really don't have time or the ability to do a major refactor so I need a simple and quick solution to make this work, how doesn't really matter to me just that it works and is not super slow or insecure.

Comment: Do the state load during or before the creation of the root component. Either in [mounted](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) or [beforeMount](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount). Most likely named App.vue.

Comment: Isn't that what I tried above and it failed? I did it in both mounted and created - not at the same time

Comment: @joshk132 I didn’t see how you implemented it. Unless you want to share a working jsfiddle with the behavior you’re seeing, I don’t have any more suggestions. Sorry.